# Excel and Macros - Autofiltering using Data Validation

Tags: excel, validation, autofilter, vba

I am auto filtering using data validation, the below code works if I have the data in the same spreadsheet. However, I have data in different sheets and I want them to filter based on the selection I make on the data validation list I created.
Can some help please let me knowhow to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim r As Range
 If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    Set r = Me.AutoFilter.Range
 If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) > 0 Then
  r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("C2").Value
 Else
  r.AutoFilter Field:=1
 End If
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: if it is on a different worksheet / tab then you need to specify which worksheet range "C2" is pulling from.  Use something like:    `sheets("sheetName").Range("C2").Value`

Answer (score 0):

You need to just specifically reference the sheet you want to autofilter. See my refactor below, specifically, the `Set r = ...` line.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim r As Range

 If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then

    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Range

    If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) > 0 Then
        r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    Else
        r.AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: my work sheet name is "MappingSheet", when i try this in the code below , i get compile error "Sub or Function not defined"
Below is my code

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim r As Range
 If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then
    Set r = MappingSheet("Sheet4").AutoFilter.Range
    If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) > 0 Then
        r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    Else
        r.AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If
 End If
End Sub

Comment: @irshad - `Set r = Worksheets("MappingSheet").AutoFilter.Range`

Comment: Thank you very much Scott! It worked
i modified the code (see code below)  and it worked for me. but this doesn't end here, i have data in  another sheet which needs to populate based on the selection which i make on first sheet.

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim r As Range
     If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then
        Set r = Worksheets("MappingSheet").AutoFilter.Range
     If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) > 0 Then
          r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("D5").Value
     Else
          r.AutoFilter Field:=1
     End If
     End If
     End Sub

Comment: @Irshad - * but this doesn't end here, i have data in another sheet which needs to populate based on the selection which i make on first sheet. * - please post a new question for new issues tthat were not raised in the original question. If this answer works, please mark as such so others benefit.

Comment: Got it Scott, The below code is working, Thanks again!!

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim r As Range
 If Target.Address = "$D$5" Then
    Set r = Worksheets("MappingSheet").AutoFilter.Range
 If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) > 0 Then
  r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("D5").Value
 Else
  r.AutoFilter Field:=1
 End If
 End If
 End Sub